# с++ linux работа с терминалом

Tags: c++, linux, консоль

Здравствуйте есть такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
FILE *popen_result;

char buff[512];

popen_result = popen("dpkg --get-selections", "r");
if(!popen_result){
        printf("Can't execute command\n");
    return 0;
}
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), popen_result)!=NULL){

      printf("%s", buff);
               
        }
pclose(popen_result);
return 0;
}
```

Он выводит все установленные приложение пакеты в системе... Как можно сравнить или проверить есть ли такое приложение пытался `if(buff == "file"){...};`  Не получаться, подскажите как можно решить проблему

Comment: `if (strcmp(buff, "file") == 0) {...}`. Только подключите `cstring`

Comment: и лучше использовать getline наверное

Comment: Ну да. `fgets` оставляет `\n` в строке. Имейте это ввиду.

Comment: просто интересно: а зачем вы для такой задаче используете c++? Всмысле она просто и эффективно решается средствами bash, при этом не нужна компиляция.

Comment: `popen_result = popen("dpkg --get-selections |grep %имя_приложения%", "r");` в  `popen_results` будет только то, что соответствует `%имя_приложения%`. Или ничего не будет, если нет соответствий;

Comment: если только приложение не называется `install`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch известно же, что *на любом ЯП можно писать на shell*.

Comment: @0andriy "на любом ЯП можно писать на shell" - формулировка, конечно, оставляет желать лучше, но я спрашивал не о том, почему выбран с++ а не другой язык програмирования, а спросил почему это не сделать непосредственно с помощь shell

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch так это специально такая формулировка, суть-то как раз в «либо крестик снимите, либо трусы наденьте». (Вы только про одно плечо этой идиомы)

Comment: код на си, а в тегах плюсы)